# How can I learn pixels band values from image in screen of Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to learn pixels band values, for example when I clik on mNDWI image in screen of Earth Engine, I need learning values of red, green and blue

```
var geometry=ee.Geometry.Polygon([[38.877002459052335,40.75574968156597],
 [41.206104021552335,41.17882292442983],
 [40.645801287177335,41.59918091806734],
 [40.052539568427335,41.84517989453356],
 [39.569141130927335,41.886088143011904],
 [38.800098162177335,41.48405920501165],
 [38.877002459052335,40.75574968156597],
  ]);

var s2SR = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
              //filter start and end date
             .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2020,2020,'year'))
             .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(8,8,'month'))
             //filter according to drawn boundary
             .filterBounds(geometry)
             .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVERAGE_ASSESSMENT', 'less_than',10);

//Map.addLayer(s2SR, {bands:['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min:0, max:8000}, 's2SR');

// adding mNDWI function
var addMNDWI = function(image) {
  var mndwi = ee.Image(image).normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B11']).rename('MNDWI');
  return ee.Image(image).addBands(mndwi);
};
var mndwı=s2SR
            .map(addMNDWI);
Map.addLayer(mndwı.first(), { min:245, max:5000}, 'mndwı');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simple to view the values for *any* displayed image. First, click on the “Inspector” tab in the top right pane of the Earth Engine Code Editor.

[image: View of Inspector tab]

Then, click wherever you want on the map. The Inspector tab will display:

- The coordinates of the location you clicked.
- The values of every band of every image under that point. (When there are many, as a chart.)
- The details of the image (or feature), including properties.

[image]